# Coldfusion 11 Update 16 - Schedule Tasks have disappeared

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

We upgraded our Coldfusion 11 instance to version 16 (11,0,16,313933) and now all the scheduled tasks seems to have disappeared.

A quick google search doesn't seem to give any clues. I have had a look in the update log and there is nothing which suggests any issue.

Could someone please advise?

**Update**

Adobe are aware of this issue but they don't have a solution yet. ?!?!?!?

[Adobe CF11 update 16](https://coldfusion.adobe.com/2019/02/coldfusion-2018-release-update-2-coldfusion-2016-release-update-8-coldfusion-11-update-16-released/)

Comment: There is a lot of talk on ColdFusion's official blog about the recent release. (Don't forget to click on load more) See: https://coldfusion.adobe.com/2019/02/coldfusion-2018-release-update-2-coldfusion-2016-release-update-8-coldfusion-11-update-16-released/

Comment: Pete Freitag lists a cuple of issues known to be releated to the recent updates: https://www.petefreitag.com/item/858.cfm

Comment: Thanks @JamesAMohler  and BernhardDobler. We are really appalled with the lack of testing by Adobe before releasing an update.

Comment: Appalled is probably a kind way to describe this.  NOTE: This also applies to ColdFusion 2016; where all scheduled tasks are gone.

Answer (score 2):

### Work Around Reported

According to https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2595082
and
https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-4204021

`Recover a backup copy of and manually edit a backup copy of the neo-crons.xml. Add the below to each job and then replace the wiped out copy with this one and restart the services.`

```
<var name='clustered'>
     <string>false</string>
</var>
```